# How do you return the final redirect URL of a website using Google Apps Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, fetch

sorry if this is a simple question but I was wondering how I would be able to return the **redirected URL** of a webpage using google sheets.

Sample input webCode = SNSKS21KK

**I've attached the code below:**

```
function CHECKWEBSITE(webCode){ 
  if (webCode.map){
    return webCode.map(CHECKWEBSITE);
  } else {
    var url = 'https://www.torpedo7.co.nz/products/' + webCode;
    var redirectedUrl = ?;
    var options = {
      'muteHttpExceptions': true,
      'followRedirects': false
    };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var status = response.getResponseCode();
    
    if (redirectedUrl.includes("discontinued") || status == 302) {
      return "Not Online"; 
    } else if (status == 200 || status == 301){ 
      return "Online";
    } else {
      return "Not imported";
    }
  }
}
```

Expected redirect output = https://www.torpedo7.co.nz/products/SNSKS21KK/title/2022-e-s-force-fx-80-skis---m12-gw-f80-bindings

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var url = 'https://www.torpedo7.co.nz/products/' + webCode;
var redirectedUrl = ?;
var options = {
  'muteHttpExceptions': true,
  'followRedirects': false
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
var status = response.getResponseCode();
```

#### To:

```
var url = 'https://www.torpedo7.co.nz/products/' + webCode;
var options = {
  'muteHttpExceptions': true,
  'followRedirects': false
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
var redirectedUrl = response.getAllHeaders().Location;
var status = response.getResponseCode();
```

- `redirectedUrl` is retrieved from `Location` of the response header.
- When I tested the modified script using `webCode = SNSKS21KK`, `redirectedUrl` is `https://www.torpedo7.co.nz/products/SNSKS21KK/title/2022-e-s-force-fx-80-skis---m12-gw-f80-bindings` and `Online` was returned.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)